# How Read File And Separate Values

Tags: c, string, file-io, replace, readfile

I'm trying to read a file like this:

```
nInp=20
nOut=1
NLaye=3
hid=30
er=0.001
epo=100
epoRep=100
pscpa=0
tip=Aggr
net=emi
numPrec=0.25
prec=NH3;NOX;PM10;SO2;VOC
rag=4
```

and I must read only the values after the `=`, and with the `prec`'s values, I must separate every single value (delimited with `;`) with a new line and then I write those into a new file like:

```
NH3
NOX
PM10
SO2
VOC
```

To read after equals symbolt there is no problems, but I can't to separate `price`.

This is my function:

```
void settaggiRete(char values[20][50]){
    char line[50]; 
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char str[10][20];
    FILE *conf = fopen("conf.txt", "r");
    if(conf == NULL){
        printf("Impossibile apripre il file conf\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Ciclo sulle linee del file di configurazione
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), configRete) != NULL){
//        Leggo i valori contenuti dopo =
        if(i==10){
            char * str = values[10];
            sscanf(line, "%*[^=]=%s", values[i]);
            while ((token = strsep(line, ";")) != NULL){
                str[j] = token; 
                j++;
            }
        }else{
            sscanf(line, "%*[^=]=%s", values[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(configRete);    
}
```

So How can I separate that values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign to the array like this

```
str[j] = token;
```

try

```
strcpy(str[j], token);
```

althought that is dangerous to do, so you could

```
size_t length = strlen(token);
if (length >= sizeof(str[j]))
    length = sizeof(str[j]) - 1;
memcpy(str[j], token, length);
str[j][length] = '\0';
```

notice that you are writing safe code at the expense of trimming the token, so a better approach is to use dynamic allocation.

You also, redeclared `str` inside the loop, so delete this line

```
char * str = values[10];
```

which is presumably wrong depending on how you declared `values`.

Comment: I tried, but I had this error:` Segmentation Fault:11`

Comment: @Teo I don't see any declaration for `values`. Enable compilation warnings, there are a lot of minibugs in your code that compile without problems if you don't have warnings enabled.

Comment: yes, I pass it from `main()` so the declaration is: `char values[20][30]` and I declared `token' as 'char *`

Comment: So you need to delete the `char str[20][30];` which is confusing. There is a number of reasons that could be causing the Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Ok, but how can I understand the reason?? I delete it.. (Sorry, but I'm not very good with C)

Comment: @Teo you need to use a debugger to find the exact place in your code where the segmentation fault is happening.

Answer (score 0):

do separate at main.
like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void settaggiRete(char values[20][50]){
    char line[50]; 
    int i = 0;
    FILE *conf = fopen("conf.txt", "r");
    if(conf == NULL){
        printf("Impossibile apripre il file conf\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), conf) != NULL){
        sscanf(line, "%*[^=]=%49s", values[i++]);
    }
    fclose(conf);   
}

int main(void){
    char values[20][50] = {{0}};
    char *value11[25];
    int i, v11 = 0;

    settaggiRete(values);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(!*values[i])
            break;
        if(i==11){
            char *token, *p = values[11];
            int j = 0;
            while(token = strsep(&p, ";")){
                value11[v11++] = token;
            }
            for(j = 0; j < v11; ++j){
                printf("values[11][%d]=%s\n", j, value11[j]);
            }
        } else {
            printf("values[%d]=%s\n", i, values[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```